# Returning the indices of elements in a list

Tags: python, list

```
class ModeBool():

    def __init__(self, mode):
        self.mode = mode

class IndexOfBool():

    def __init__(self, lst):
        '''
        Creates a list of True's as it's elements based on the given number.

        >>> i1 = IndexOfBool(5)

        Should create -> [True, True, True, True, True]
        '''
        self.lst = [ModeBool(True) for i in range(lst)]

    def bool_true(self):
        new_lst = []
        for index, element in enumerate(self.lst):
            if element is True:
                new_lst.append(index)
        return new_lst
```

However, when I call `bool_true` it does not return the correct result:

```
i1 = IndexOfBool(10)
i1.bool_true()
[]
```

What it should have returned:

```
i1 = IndexOfBool(10)
i1.bool_true()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Not too sure why it doesn't return what is expected. Also, if I were to replace `ModeBool(True)` with `ModeBool(False)` than it should create a list of `False`s instead. And if I call `bool_true` on the list of `False`s than it should `return []`.

Comment: what's the point of `ModeBool` ?

Comment: Oh, I was going to add more stuff to it.

Comment: You can always regularly debug your script by using the `print` statement to see what your variables actually point to. If you put `print self.lst` at the end of the `__init__` method of your `IndexOfBool` class, you will immediately discover the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line

```
self.lst = [ModeBool(True) for i in range(lst)]
```

should be

```
self.lst = [ModeBool(True).mode for i in range(lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`element is True` is *false*, as each element was created with `ModeBool(True)`.

add this to `ModeBool`, and don't compare with `is`:

```
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.mode
```

for python2, use `__nonzero__`